# gps coordinates is not working in marshmallow

Tags: android, gps, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-sdk-tools

I have implemented the code to get the latitude and longitude it works fine for below version 23, but not working for android Marshmallow. I have set the run time permissions also but still not working, below is my code where I am calling method.

```
private void configureButton() {
    get_gps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

                    }, 10);
                }
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                configureButton();
                return;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you handle `onRequestPermissionsResult` method? If not, you should implement it, if permission was granted you should call `locationManage.requestLocationUpdates()` then.

Comment: yes i am handling that too

Comment: post code of that method then

Comment: you need to change `grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` to `grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` as you waiting for permission grant.

Comment: nope i tried that even this is also not working